# Add weighted numbers along a process map flow in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a process map in excel which I visualize with visio. I have processes and decisions. Processes take time, and the decision outcome is weighted with a probability. Assuming my numbers are correct (which they are probably not ;)), this should allow me to calculate the average execution time of the whole process.

Now in order to get the average execution time, I need to summarize along the paths, taking into account the weights. This in itself is not a difficult task, however I would prefer a forumlar that is not specific to the current state of the map, but would be able to update itself if I add more processes and decisions. In principle this should be possible with some sort of recursive function, because the paths are defined in the excel sheet. However I am a bit lost on how I would implement a recursive function in excel, if that is even possible.

Has anyone ever done this? Or has a hint on how this could work? Or do I need to resort to external tools?

EDIT: Here is an Example for my excel:
[image]

So "Process Step" and "Next Step ID" together define multiple paths from "Start" to "End". Decisions have outcomes with certain weight (expressed in percent) which is the probability that the first of the two "Next Step ID"s will be taken.

So in this case it would start something like this: 1 + 0.4*(2 ...) + 0.6*(2 ...) ... as you can see, even if I would never modify the excel, its quite hard to get it right dong it manually. Now imagine I add a few steps ...

I hope this clarifies the task. I am trying to solve this with VBA now ... but I have never used VBA so I would still appreciate any hints.

Comment: I'm guessing you might be able to use the =`AVERAGEIFS()` formula, possibly nesting multiplication within it (for the weighting). If you need more than that, please edit your question to include mocked up data and expected results.

Comment: You can try to provide the sample here, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally solved this myself with a recursive VBA function:

```
Function ProcessTime(row, time) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    ' Define Columns
    ProcessStepCol = 2
    NextStepIDCol = 4
    ShapeTypeCol = 6
    TimeCol = 7
    PyesCol = 8
    ' Do actual calculation
    ShapeType = Worksheets("Process").Cells(row, ShapeTypeCol).Value
    
    ' Exit at the End
    If ShapeType = "End" Then
        ProcessTime = time
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Simply add current time if we have a Process
    If ShapeType = "Process" Then
        NextStepRow = GetNextStepRows(row, 0)
        TimeOfThisRow = Worksheets("Process").Cells(row, TimeCol).Value
        ProcessTime = time + ProcessTime(NextStepRow, TimeOfThisRow)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Add wheights to branches if we have a Decision
    If ShapeType = "Decision" Then
        NextStepRowYes = GetNextStepRows(row, 0)
        NextStepRowNo = GetNextStepRows(row, 1)
        P_yes = Worksheets("AlertProcess").Cells(row, PyesCol).Value / 100
        P_no = 1 - P_yes
        ProcessTime = time + (P_yes * ProcessTime(NextStepRowYes, 0)) + (P_no * ProcessTime(NextStepRowNo, 0))
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function


' Find the row of the next step
Function GetNextStepRows(row, stepNo) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    ' Define Columns
    ProcessStepCol = 2
    NextStepIDCol = 4
    ' Do actual calculation
    NextStepIDs = Worksheets("AlertProcess").Cells(row, NextStepIDCol).Value
    NextStepIDsSplit = Split(NextStepIDs, ",")
    NextStepID = NextStepIDsSplit(stepNo)
    GetNextStepRows = Worksheets("AlertProcess").Range("B:B").Find(What:=NextStepID).row
End Function
```

And yes, I am aware that this is not the most elegant piece of code ;)